# How can I generate paginated grouped data in SQL

Tags: sql, pagination

I wish to paginate grouped data but I have the restriction of only being able to display a limited number of rows (not results) per page.

For example, each page of 20 rows will display one or more groups of results. Each group will consist of:

- a row containing the group title
- a row for each result in the group

If the results in a group span across multiple pages, the 'group title' row will be repeated on the subsequent page(s).

So far I am able to `union` the results and group titles ordered in such a way that they form a table of rows that I could page easily.

```
select * from (

    select f.Id, f.Name, p.Id As ProviderId, 2 as RowType,
        'Result' as RowTypeTitle
    from Fund f
    inner join Provider p on f.ProviderId = p.Id

    union

    select distinct f2.ProviderId as Id, p2.Name, f2.ProviderId, 1 as RowType,
        'Group Title' as RowTypeTitle
    from Fund f2
    inner join Provider p2 on f2.ProviderId = p2.Id

) u

order by u.ProviderId, u.RowType asc
```

What I am missing from the SQL above are the duplicate 'group title' rows where for example I need to return only 20 'rows' per page. How might I be able to refactor the SQL to incorporate these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the function ROW_NUMBER you will be able to generate a number of row. Then you keep a count of where you are.

Idealy, you could simplify the syntax with the "With" clause. But here is the code with your query as is.

ex:

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by t.ProviderId, t.RowType )/20 AS PageID ,* 
     from (

         select * from (

            select f.Id, f.Name, p.Id As ProviderId, 2 as RowType,
                  'Result' as RowTypeTitle
            from Fund f
            inner join Provider p on f.ProviderId = p.Id

         union

            select distinct f2.ProviderId as Id, p2.Name, f2.ProviderId, 1 as RowType,
                 'Group Title' as RowTypeTitle
           from Fund f2
           inner join Provider p2 on f2.ProviderId = p2.Id )y)  t 
         )u


         order by u.ProviderId, u.RowType asc
```

Then the "PageID" will tell you on wich page to put the data, 20 at a time.

Comment: I have run this and it just seems to add a grouped 'rowid' column. This isn't really what I was after. I need the results grouped with a group title row adding every 20 rows and at the beginning of each group.

Comment: I havent tried exactly the query since I don't have the table definition and data. With ROW_NUMBER, you should be able to have a rowid from 0 to 99999 depending on how many rows you have. If not, change the "PARTITION BY" and you'll see that it works. Then, you change de "WHERE u.ROW_ID BETWEEN 0 AND 20" to be BETWEEN 20 AND 40, an so on.

Comment: The schema is a straightforward one to many relationship between Fund and Provider and should be easy to set up. I have run your script and it does not do what I have asked for in the question. It also doesn't do what you suggest it should in your answer.

Comment: You should try again. I created the table, put data in it and tried the query, it works. I changed the query

Comment: Thankyou for updating your query but as I say in my first comment, all this does is add a rowid column. This is not what I am asking for in my question. For example, if a group of funds are split across two pages, your solution would not include the group title row as the first in the second page.

Comment: I changed it again. Now it will show a PageID column, telling you on wich page to put your data, 20 at a time.

Comment: It's almost there. I can adapt this to nearly do what I need. I have modified the over statement to be `(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t.ProviderId, t.RowType ) - 1) / 20` to take into account that the first row will always have the header applied.